# How do I give my install4j Uninstaller a custom name?

Tags: install4j, uninstallation

We do some pretty unorthodox stuff with the way we handle our installations. We make many different installers for different products and have them all install into the same directory. Because of this, the uninstaller will have the name of the last product installed into this directory.

I would like to give the uninstaller a new name instead, so I'm wondering if there's a way to override the title of the window once you launch the uninstaller so that I can give it something more generic.

Comment: I forgot to also mention, I'm on Install4j 5.1.15 at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Installer->Screen & Actions, select the uninstaller and edit the "Executable name" property.

Comment: I need to change the title of the window for the uninstaller once it launches. I'm OK with the uninstaller just being named uninstaller.exe. I edited my original question to clarify this. Sorry.

Comment: You could call `((JFrame)Util.getParentWindow()).setTitle("My title")` in the "Post-activation" script of the first screen.